# Why do Object.prototype and Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype) return different things?

Tags: javascript

```
Object.prototype
=> {}
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)
=> [ 'constructor',
  'toString',
  'toLocaleString',
  'valueOf',
  'hasOwnProperty',
  'isPrototypeOf',
  'propertyIsEnumerable',
  '__defineGetter__',
  '__lookupGetter__',
  '__defineSetter__',
  '__lookupSetter__',
  '__proto__' ]
   var x = {foo:2}
   x
=> { foo: 2 }
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x)
=> [ 'foo' ]
```

Why does `Object.prototype` is empty but calling `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)` it is really not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably down to the fact that all of `Object.prototype`'s properties are *non-enumerable*. It'll vary by console, but apparently the console you're using isn't showing non-enumerable properties when you ask it to show you `Object.prototype`. In contrast, `getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array containing the names of all "own" properties of the object you pass in whose names are strings, regardless of whether they're enumerable; your console is then showing you the contents of that array. (If you used `Object.keys(Object.prototype)` instead, you'd get an empty array, because `Object.keys` only gives you the names of *enumerable* properties.)

In your `x` example, the object has an *enumerable* `foo` property. I suspect if you did this:

```
var x = {};
Object.defineProperty(x, "foo", {value: 2});
x
```

...in your console, you'd see `{}` like you do for `Object.prototype`, because that would define `foo` as a non-enumerable property.

Comment: Just adding a point: `getOwnPropertyNames` will return the own property names no matter enumerable or non-enumerable.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: I said that (*"regardless of whether they're enumerable"*).

Comment: And why in the second case `getOwnPropertyNames` returns only `foo`?

Comment: @Cristy: Because `foo` is the only *own* property that object has. All the rest are *inherited* properties.

Comment: So, in the first case the Object is actuslly the `Object` class and in the second case it's only an instance of `Object` that prototypically inherits it.

Comment: @Cristy: In the first case, it's the object assigned to `Object.prototype` (not the `Object` class). In the second case it's an object that inherits from that object and also has its own `foo` property.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, maybe an off-topic question, but does the object Object have the internal [[Prototype]] pointing to Object.prototype? Because as far I see Object.toString() works too, but toString is an Object.prototype's property.

Comment: @welcome: The `toString` that `Object` inherits isn't `Object.prototype.toString`, it's [`Function.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.tostring). A better example might be `valueOf` or `hasOwnProperty`, which are on `Object.prototype` but not on `Function.prototype`. `Object` has them, because it is a true function, so it inherits from `Function.prototype`, which inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder does you mean Function internal [[Prototype]] inherits from Object.prototype or Function.prototype inherits from Object.prototype?

Comment: @welcome: `Function`, like `Object`, is a true function, and so its [[Prototype]] is `Function.prototype`, which inherits from `Object.prototype`.